# Отправка сообщение по нажатию enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как мне сделать , чтобы при нажатии Enter у меня отправлялось сообщение ?
Искал - искал , нашел код для отправки при нажатии Enter , но дальше перезагрузки страницы не ушел :(
Есть html :

```
<input id="message_text" type="text">
<button  id="send_enter" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="run()">войти</button>
```

Про функцию run

```
if(userID == 0 ) login();
 else send();
```

Функция send :

```
var msg = $("#message_text").val();
$("#message_text").val('');

var zapros = {
url: "main.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
  action:"send_message",
  message: msg,
  userID: userID
},
success: function(data){
  //alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
  update_messages();
}
};
  $.ajax(zapros);
 };
```

Comment: На самом деле, правильнее (семантичнее) и проще - поместить инпуты в форму (`<form>`) и обрабатывать на ней событие `submit`, которое автоматически триггерится при нажатии клавиши Enter в любом из инпутов формы. Не добавляю ответом т.к. эта более грамотная реализация через стандартный HTML, а вопрос задан о JS-реализации (которая хоть и является ненужным усложнением, все же остается темой вопроса).

Answer (score 2):

Каждая клавиша имеет свой идентификатор и зная данный код можно повесить событие.

> Javascript

```
document.getElementById("send_enter").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        run();
        return false;
    }
});
```

> JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send_enter').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            run();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй на кнопке в событии **onclick** добавить `event.preventDefault()`

Вот так:

```
<button  id="send_enter" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="event.preventDefault();run();">войти</button>
```

Comment: Сделал , при нажатии на ентер ничего не происходит :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key